# Using sed in Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm really new at scripting and regex so I apologize in advance. Essentially I'm writing a shell script using sed that will replace pragmas in my code. Here's an example:

#pragma foo=value   //some comment

To

OUTPUT(value) //some comment

I'm trying to replace the expression on top with the expression on the bottom while still keeping the comment. I'm not too sure how to store value as a "variable" for the new expression, as all the examples I've seen replace some text with other text without treating anything as a variable. Could I get some help :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some useful links for further learning -

[Learn about regexs here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)

[Test and trial and error your regexs here](https://regexr.com/)

---

Now regarding the question itself, `sed` can do more than just replace text, but when it comes to replacing, the syntax is `sed -E 's/regex/replacement/flags'`.

As you may have seen, regex has no concept of "variables", instead it has what's called "capture groups".

Let's start with a simple regex to find your exact example: `#pragma foo=value //some comment`

To work on any 'value' we can replace 'value' with `\w+`, which means any amount of letters or numbers: `#pragma foo=\w+ //some comment`

Now the last piece of the puzzle is to be able to use the value itself in the replacement.
So first to put a piece of the regex in a group you simple wrap in parentheses: `#pragma foo=(\w+) //some comment`

Now we can use `\1` to reference the first capture group in our regex, so the replacement string will look like this: `OUTPUT(\1) //some comment`

Now to put it all together in a `sed` command, I don't think you want any flags here, but you might notice that the `sed` syntax includes slashes, but so does our regex and replacement. So we can either escape them with a backslash, but actually `sed` doesn't care if we use slashes or anything else to separate the arguments, so we can instead use for example `sed 's|regex|replacement|flags'`.

The result is `sed -E 's|#pragma foo=(\w+) //some comment|OUTPUT(\1) //some comment|'`

The `-E` flag tells `sed` we're using regex features instead of regular text, without it our regex won't actually work.

---

There might be better ways to write your regex exactly like you want, but I think this should get you started.

Lastly, you may want to check out `awk`, another really powerful shell command that can edit text, you may like it better.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was really helpful :)